# Is it possible to remove the default padding while keeping the position relative?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried many solution to remove the default padding but with the position being **absolute**, i want to know if it is possible to have my panels **width 100%** , and **padding-left 0** but at the same time keeping the **position relative**.

This is the HTML :

```
 <div class="mainbody container-fluid " style="width:800px; margin:0 auto; 
    background-color: red">
 <div class="row">
     <div  class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">


        <div class="iduser">random
                    <span>
                       <div></div>
                    </span>
                 </div>
        <div  class="panel panel-default col-md-12">
           <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="pull-left">

                 <div class="panel-heading">random</div>
                 <div class="seperate"></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>random </p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="panel-footer"> random

                 </div> 
               </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div> <!-- /.row -->
 </div>   <!-- /.main body-->
```

This is the CSS :

```
  * {     /* Changing the round nav bar edges */
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
 }
 body {  /*Background properties*/
overflow-y: scroll;
background-color: #e9ebee;
}
.panel-default{    /* Context back panel*/

border-color: black;
height: 240px;
width: 540px;
position: absolute;
}

.panel-heading{    /* Tittle  */
background-color: brown;
width: 35em;
margin-left: 1px;
position: relative;  

}
.panel-body{    /*   main body */



}
.panel-footer{   /* Reacting panel footer */
background-color: gray;
position: relative;
width: 99.5%;
left: 0;
margin-left: 1px;
bottom: 0;
margin-bottom:1px;
border-top-width: 0px ;


/*padding: 0; when finished*/



}

.seperate{
 position: absolute; 
 border:1px solid #000;
 width: 99.5%;
 left: 1px;
}
```

[This is how it looks like to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDfff.jpg)

Comment: are you talking about panel-footer? and what do you want it to be 100% of? because currently it has a width of 99.5% of panel-body

Comment: Position of what relative? Inner text?

Comment: @notblakeshelton i have given it the width of 99.5%  but it does not apply it if i keep the position relative. Only if i changed it to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is no padding and margin, the approach is a little complicated. I believe if you use padding and margin selectively and strategically, it will be easier.

You can add some unicode escaped space characters `\0000a0` as padding between the items in your `ul` list. In order to do this you will need pseudo elements `:after` you `li` tags

**Here is my idea for getting that website layout in the link provided**

Create a sub container called `center_bar`  and add your `ul` list inside

Take out the anchor with label `Brand` from your `ul` list and add it inside the `center_bar` div

Now you have two elements in your center bar div 1.Your `Brand` anchor and 2. your `ul` list

Add a width to your `center_bar` in % and display it `inline-block`

Inside your `center_bar` float  your `ul`  tag to the right

Add a clear fix for that floated element

Now apply a text-align `center` to your `nav-bar` so that inline-block `center_bar` will center in the middle.

Closest I can get you is this..See snippet (Ensure you take out all the border in this snippet)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(114, 40, 114);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: rgb(114, 40, 114);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul #brand {
  text-align: center;
}

ul #about {}

ul #portfolio {}

ul #contact {}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

ul li {
  float: right;
}

ul {
  border: solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#center_bar {
  width: 85%;
  border: solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

#center_bar:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
  clear: both;
}

li:after {
  content: "\0000a0\0000a0\0000a0";
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div id="center_bar">
    <a href="#">Brand</a>
    <ul>
      <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li id="portfolio"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```